# Does setting objects to null the same as garbage collecting in c++?

Tags: c++

I have a question here that asks me that if setting the properties of class to null is the same as collecting a garbage in c++. And how this is related to memory management. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example#:~:text=Minimal%20and%20readable,correctly%20formatted%20on%20Stack%20Overflow.) before posting questions.

Comment: I am voting it to close, cause these seems to be an class assignment question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no garbage collection in c++. If you do not deallocate memory it will not be deallocated. Once an object is destroyed however all member objects are destroyed as well, BUT pointers are not the objects they are pointing to, therefore those objects would have to be destroyed manually. And to your question: If you set something to NULL, the value would just become NULL, but the object would remain.

Example:

```cpp
struct A {
    int a;
    int* b;
};

void func(){
    // Create a stack allocated variable
    A stack_allocated = {5, new int(5)};
    // Create a heap allocated variable
    A* heap_allocated = new A({5,new int(5)});
} // Upon exiting stack_allocated is destroyed, but heap_allocated is not.
// It is also important to note that stack_allocated.b is not destroyed only
// the pointer to it. Use delete to get rid of those.
```

Answer (score 2):

C++ does not have any garbage collection.

Everything that is created in automatic memory is cleaned up, well, automatically when it goes out of scope.

Everything that is created dynamically must be destroyed explicitly. That is where smart pointers come into play, to handle that cleanup for you. You can assign `nullptr` to a smart pointer to destroy/release what it is pointing at, but assigning `nullptr` to a raw pointer does not destroy anything.

You can't assign `nullptr" to an object, unless it explicitly implements support for that, which 99% of objects do not.